# TV show where a kid summons/transforms into a monster to battle

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

I'm looking for a TV series from around 2010-2014. I think it was an animated show following a kid who builds(?) things that he can use to duel people. In a duel, it's 1-v-1 and you pick a battlefield, then either play as or instruct your monster to fight.

I think the kid had black hair and I think the monsters were more human-like in appearance (standing on two legs with two arms holding weapons), rather than monstrous.

It's not *Chaotic* or *Kaijudo*.

Comment: What did the kid look like? Especially in regard to his hair colour? And can you describe any other significant characters or monsters in the show? Having some visual cues to look for really helps to narrow things down with formulaic shows like this.

Comment: honestly it was so long ago I barely remember anything. I think he had black hair and I think the monsters where more human like in appearance (standing on 2 legs with 2 arms holding weapons) rather than a monster

Answer (score 2):

Not a lot to go on here, but I'm going to throw out ***[Redakai](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2021833/)*** (2011–2013) as a possibility, since it fits your timeframe, and stars a black-haired boy who can transform into a humanoid battle creature.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redakai:_Conquer_the_Kairu):

> *Redakai: Conquer the Kairu*, also known simply as *Redakai*, is an animated series that premiered on YTV and later Teletoon in Canada on July 9, 2011, on Cartoon Network in the United States on July 16, 2011 and on Canal J and Gulli in France on October 22, 2011. The series was created by Vincent Chalvon Demersay and David Michel and was co-produced by Canada's Spin Master Entertainment and France's Marathon Media in association with Canal J and Gulli. Like *Totally Spies!* and *Martin Mystery*, which were also produced by Marathon, the show's animation style has been compared to that of anime.

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/Redakai):

> The Cartoon centers around a boy named Ky Stax and his friends Boomer and Maya who quest around the world trying to collect an energy called "Kairu", the life energy of the universe before the villain Lokar and his minions find it first. They do this by fighting other teams and transforming into monsters. The episodes are different every week without much of an overarching plot.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be [Medabots](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0293731/)?
It was made in 1999-2000, but there could have been replays.
The hero is a black-haired boy and he battles with robots.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medabots):

> Medabots, known in Japan as Medarot (メダロット, Medarotto), is a Japanese-Canadian role-playing video game franchise created by Rin Horuma (Horumarin) and currently owned by Imagineer. The main series of RPGs focus on collecting and battling with the titular robots. The bulk of the games releases have been on Nintendo platforms, including the Game Boy family, Nintendo GameCube, and the DS and 3DS handhelds.
>
> The series was adapted into a Japanese anime television series spanning two adaptations. The first was animated by Bee Train while the second, Medarot Damashii, was animated by Production I.G. The television series originally aired on TV Tokyo from July 2, 1999 to March 30, 2001. Both series were originally licensed and localized into English by Nelvana and were broadcast on YTV in Canada and Fox Kids and ABC Family in the United States from 2001 to 2004.

[image: Medabot's bluray cover]